# Is there a way to start commandline processes in a new commandline window from a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using

```
Start-Process "<PathToFile>.bat"
```

For .bat files from a lengthy script in Powershell (v3). However, the commandline window pops up for a moment and is immediately closed and the process that normally runs on the commandline, runs in the background with no indication wether it's finished or if any errors occured.

Is there a way to force the command window to stay open until the user exits the window (after the .bat ran)? I suppose even if there is a way that the command window stays open, the PS script will continue to run in the background?

Comment: Execute `cmd /k file.bat`

Comment: tried Start-Process -wait allready? You could also open the file in your current window with -nonewwindow or redirect output with -redirectstandardoutput and errors with -redirectstandarderror

Comment: /k doesn't seem to work. The commandline opens in the background. Since it requires user interaction in the end, the script is stuck as soon as it calls the commandline.

Are you sure /k works as described?

Comment: @Paul -wait really did seem to do the trick for one of the 2 .bat files. The 2nd one still doesn't launch with start-process <batpath> -wait ... but maybe it's coding error on my side. Still checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Alex K CMD /K opens a CMD window and then keeps it open.

If you use CMD /C it will call the file, run the commands/process and then exit.

Comment: Sorry for not replying so fast, I had to wait for another test case.

I tried cmd /k and the window did not even pop up, let alone stay open. For reference, a little more complete code snippet:

`    $DMMainSQLBAT = $DM3Dir + "deploy\sql\dm_mainsql.bat"

    "sqlplus /nolog @dm_main.sql" | Out-File $DMMainSQLBAT -Encoding ascii

    $ouput = cmd /k $DMMainSQLBAT`

When I execute it, the commandline is opened in the back. Thing is, the commands require you to hit a key at the end, so the script is stuck there because the cmd process never terminates.

Comment: I just found out that cmd and cmd.exe were in $psUnsupportedConsoleApplications. Removed it, now plain cmd opens on the ps command line, but I can't seem to call any .bat from there. Specifically I tried

cmd "<pathtobat>" and cmd \k "<pathtobat>"

Comment: Have you used CMD /C '<pathtobat> as this does not require any button presses to proceed once its task is completed. I just tested both on mine, using a bat to call something like notepad and CMD /K just leave the powershell cursor blinking and C opens Notepad and then returns me to the prompt.

It could be to do with how you are setting up the variable, is there any need to have two quotes or are you missing a plus between "deploy\sql\dm_mainsql.bat" "sqlplus /nolog @dm_main.sql"

Comment: Change it to "deploy\sql\dm_mainsql.bat" + " sqlplus /nolog @dm_main.sql" or to "deploy\sql\dm_mainsql.bat sqlplus /nolog @dm_main.sql" and give it a try.

Comment: Comment came out garbled, designating code doesn't seem to work in comments, just answers. What I do is: 1) set the directory 2) create a .bat with the command I want to execute 3) call cmd /k $pathtobat

Comment: Also start-process <pathtobat> -wait seemes to work with just one of the 2 .bat files I call. Really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it never worked for me with cmd /c. Since I also needed parameters to be handed over to the programm called from the commandline, I opted to write a temporary proxy bat that held the call to the program and the parameters.

Pseudocode here:

```
"ProgramName /Parameters" | Out-File DirOfTempBatFile -Encoding ascii
$output = Start-Process DirOfTempBatFile -wait
```

This calls the program (sqlplus with parameters) with keeping the command window open. Additionally, you can access the output of the sqlplus debug messages via $output.